# How can i format the web socket response in real time

Tags: json, typescript, websocket, rxjs, real-time

I have a websocket that has a object response like this :

```
{
0: "2019"
1: "rice"
2: "samsung"
3: "james"
}
```

and i need to change the key name and keep the values;

And everytime i receive a new response i want to change the key and keep the values in real time.
Is there anyway to do this ? like a model saying that 0 is Year, and 1 is Food

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing from WebSocket protocol. But you can easily write a function to make it upon reception of a new message for example.

```
this.ws.on('message', (data: { 0: string; 1: string }) => {
      const result = {
        Year: data[0],
        Food: data[1]
      };
    });
```

Where `result` would be the output that you are looking for